# Input не растягивается по ширине

Tags: html, css, input

Доброй ночи, перепробовал все что можно. Суть проблемы в том, что в строке 4 элемента, 3 селекта и 1 инпут, инпут надо растянуть во всю оставшуюся ширину страницы, что бы я не делал - либо фиксированный размер, либо инпут переходит на новую строку и занимает 100% страницы :/

Демка - https://jsfiddle.net/Lgwp2vL4/

```
    .input {
  height: 30px;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 1px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто обернуть их в span'ы:

```css
div { display: table; width: 100%; }
span { display: table-cell; width: 0; }
span:last-child { width: 100%; }
input { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div>
  <span><select><option>abacaba</select></span>
  <span><select><option>a</select></span>
  <span><select><option>other</select></span>
  <span><input></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот это отлично, но возникает проблема из-за того, что у меня в спанах есть текст для описания селекта, и все разметка разлетается. Можно заменить спан на что-то другое? заранее спасибо

Comment: Так и стилизуй те спаны, не надо новые добавлять. Ну и `white-space: nowrap` добавь для них, а для следующего уровня вложенности верни `normal`.

Comment: помогло, еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Используй флексбоксы.

```css
.some-class {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.filters {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
        <div class="some-class">
          <div class="filters">Показать по
            <select class="select">
              <option>3</option>
              <option>6</option>
              <option>12</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="filters">Тип
            <select class="select">
              <option>All</option>
              <option>Regular</option>
              <option>VIP</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="filters">Количество шаблонов
            <select class="select">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <label>
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Поиск">
          </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e9ed;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.title {
  color: #7387a7;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e9ed;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.filters {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #72879c;
  padding: 0 27px 0 27px;
}

.select {
  /* flex-grow: 1; если хотите чтобы они заняли всю свободную область*/
  flex-basis: 60%;
  color: #72879c;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0 23px 0 11px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 1px;
  }
field {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
  
.input {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="title">Посетители</h1>
    <fieldset>
    <field>
      <label for="select" class="filters">Показать по     </label>
        <select name="select" class="select">
          <option>3</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>12</option>
        </select>
     </field>
     <field>
      <label for="select" class="filters">Тип
      </label>
        <select name="select" class="select">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Regular</option>
          <option>VIP</option>
        </select>
      </field>
      <field>
      <label for="select" class="filters">Количество шаблонов
      </label>
        <select name="select" class="select">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </field>
      <field>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Поиск">
      </field>
    </fieldset>
```